Cloud Function keeps hanging (Firebase emulator) PYTHON
I'm testing some firebase cloud functions locally with the emulator. The problem is that in my post function when I send a body of type json the function keeps hanging, if I send nothing or in text format it goes alright.
This is what i did:
# Welcome to Cloud Functions for Firebase for Python!
# To get started, simply uncomment the below code or create your own.
# Deploy with `firebase deploy`

from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app, credentials, firestore
import json
import flask

cred = credentials.Certificate("../firebase.json")
initialize_app(cred)

# Initialize flask app
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.post("/widgets")
def add_widget():
    try:
        # new_widget = flask.request.json
        # print(flask.request.json)
        print(flask.request.content_type)
        return flask.Response(status=201, response=json.dumps({"message": "Widget added successfully"}), content_type='application/json')
    except Exception as e:
        return flask.Response(status=500, response="Error: " + str(e))


# Expose Flask app as a single Cloud Function:
@https_fn.on_request()
def httpsflaskexample(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    with app.request_context(req.environ):
        return app.full_dispatch_request()

As you can see I have 2 prints, if I uncomment the first print and send a body of type json it prints it but the code doesn't return the response, it hangs. On the other hand, if I don't send anything the code returns the response.
EDIT:
I found out that this happens just on my windows pc. I have a laptop with linux and it runs well. What can it be?
